# How to invoke classes dynamically without using eval?

Tags: ruby, eval

Is it possible to get rid of the **eval** statement below? The code below filters out all classes which are derived from type BaseClass. Afterwards those classes are instantiated and method 'hello' is called.

```
module MySpace

  class BaseClass
    def hello; print "\nhello world"; end
  end

  class A<BaseClass
    def hello; super; print ", class A was here"; end
  end

  class B<BaseClass
    def hello; super; print ", I'm just a noisy class"; end
  end

  MySpace.constants.each do | e |
    c=eval(e)
    if c < BaseClass
      c.new.hello
    end
  end

end
```

So after execution the output is:

**hello world, I'm just a noisy class

hello world, class A was here**

I think unnecessary use of **eval** is evil. And I'm not sure if the use of **eval** is mandatory here. Is there is a smarter way in invoking all classes from type "BaseClass" dynamically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
c = MySpace.const_get(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `class_eval` instead?

```
------------------------------------------------------ Module#class_eval
     mod.class_eval(string [, filename [, lineno]])  => obj
     mod.module_eval {|| block }                     => obj
------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Evaluates the string or block in the context of _mod_. This can be
     used to add methods to a class. +module_eval+ returns the result of
     evaluating its argument. The optional _filename_ and _lineno_
     parameters set the text for error messages.

        class Thing
        end
        a = %q{def hello() "Hello there!" end}
        Thing.module_eval(a)
        puts Thing.new.hello()
        Thing.module_eval("invalid code", "dummy", 123)

    produces:

        Hello there!
        dummy:123:in `module_eval': undefined local variable
            or method `code' for Thing:Class
```

Answer (score 0):

eval is the only way I know of to turn a string into a constant.  Its even the way rails does it:
http://api.rubyonrails.com/classes/Inflector.html#M001638

The odd thing is that constants returns strings.